# Does VMWare workstation 10 support VT-X passthrough and if so, how can I enable it?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation, vt-x

I want to run Cuckoo inside a VMWare Workstation virtual machine together with Virtual Box (also running within a virtual machine). Is there a way to enable VT-X passthrough so Virtual Box can also leverage VT-X?

Comment: I'm not talking about enabling VT-X, I'm talking about VT-X passthrough to support nested hypervisors

Comment: This is a sensible question with a good answer that is very hard to find anywhere else.  It should be "reopened" or whatever the opposite of "closed" is. :-P

Answer (score 4):

This is not a duplicated question.

What OP is trying to do is something like this:

`Host A(with VT-X support)->virtual machine B-->some applications need VT-X`

and getting VT-X support **inside** B so applications -- may be another VM or emulator -- running inside B, can take advantage of vt-x.

Its called "Nested Hardware Virtualization", supported by VMWare, and can enable it by editing the `.vmx` file and adding a line

```
vhv.enable = "TRUE"
```

[Source](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2034803)

But this does [NOT](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) work on VirtualBox "host".

Comment: Awesome.  Took me forever to find this info... thanks!